# How to not be remove from playstore due to new google play privacy policy of storage permission

Tags: flutter, google-play

recently googleplay console send me this note

```
Starting May 5th, you must let us know why your app requires broad storage access

We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of your app bundles or APKs.

Developers with apps on devices running Android 11+ must use Scoped Storage to give users better access control over their device storage. To release your app on Android 11 or newer after May 5th, you must either:

Update your app to use more privacy friendly best practices, such as the Storage Access Framework or Media Store API
Update your app to declare the All files access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in the manifest file, and complete the All files access permission declaration in Play Console from May 5th
Remove the All files access permission from your app entirely
For apps targeting Android 11, the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag will be ignored. You must use the All files access permission to retain broad access.

Apps requesting access to the All files access permission without a permitted use will be removed from Google Play, and you won't be able to publish updates.
```

I use flutter and the only package who need permission from storage is image_picker from the official flutter_dev team so this isn't an unmaintained package or noob package...

I'm search `requestLegacyExternalStorage`in the manifest of image_picker but nothing found. How can I be sure that even if I remove all the package it's will be ok ?

So I don't understand why I have this note from googleplay, perhaps this is just to prevent, and I'm OK with rules. But perhaps not and I don't want to risk to have my app remove fro the store the 5th May. So How can I be sure, to do the right things to not have my app remove ...
thank you

EDIT: it's seems to have a bug in this official package, when user select camera, there is no dialog to accept or denied the storage permission. I don't know if it's due to that or if I will have same problem with all the plugin

Answer (score 0):

As they requested for an explanation you can reply them saying your issue and you can also request them to guide you if there is any specific changes needed this would help while they consider removing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).